# tkinter keyboard shortcuts issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a drop-down menu with a keyboard shortcut that calls a function whenever I click it.

```
from tkinter import *


class app:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('500x380')
        self.root.title('Text Editor')
        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.submenu = Menu(self.menu)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Tab', menu=self.submenu)
        self.submenu.add_command(label='Do Somthing', command=self.dosomthing)
        self.root.bind('<Control-r>', self.dosomthing)

    def dosomthing(self, event):
        print('Somthing Was Done!')

root = Tk()
app()
root.mainloop()
```

The shortcut is working perfectly. However, whenever I want to just click the label instead of using the shortcut, it says: TypeError: dosomthing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

How do I fix it so I can click the label and also use the keyboard shortcut??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the event parameter I the dosomthing method to *args because Tkinter does not pass any parameter when calling the method in the menu.

it should look like this:

```
def dosomthing(self, *args):
    print('Somthing Was Done!')
```

if you never used *args it's a list with the parameters passed, for example, if you have this:

```
def method(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)

method("something","another thing")
```

it will return

something

another thing

you could also use lambda

```
    self.root.bind('<Control-r>', lambda e: self.dosomthing())

def dosomthing(self):
    print('Somthing Was Done!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been correctly answered by @Tartyto, But for someone else who may view this question in the future here are the reasons why this occurs and which of the methods mentioned by @Tartyto is better.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Art for letting me know the mistakes with my answer, this edit is with the hope of resolving those mistakes.

Normally when you bind a function to a keybinding in tkinter you do it similar to how you did it like so -:

```
def __init__(self, ...) :
    self.root.bind('KEYBINDING', self.do_something)
    return

def do_something(self, event) :
    print('Did something....')
    return
```

So what happens here is that our callback function accepts an event argument which is passed by the bind function when it calls the callback.

But when the same function is called on your menu button being pressed, the callback function is called without any argument being passed, this results in python prompting you to pass the event argument for the callback function.

And to solve this we can either make the second argument optional, pass the second argument manually when its not being passed, or we can set a default value for the second argument. All are valid ways of doing it.

```
# OPTIONAL ARGUMENT WAY
def __init__(self, ....) :
    root.bind('KEYBINDING', self.do_something)
    ...
    return

def do_something(self, *args) :
    print('Did something....')
    return

# DEFAULT ARGUMENT WAY
def __init__(self, ....) :
    root.bind('KEYBINDING', self.do_something)
    ...
    return

def do_something(self, event = None) :
    print('Did something....')
    return

# LAMBDA WAY
def __init__(self, ....) :
    root.bind('KEYBINDING', lambda : self.do_something(None))
    ...
    return

def do_something(self, event) :
    print('Did something....')
    return
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the OP's question well. `root.bind('KEYBINDING', lambda my_event : self.do_something(my_event))` is essentially the same as `root.bind('KEYBINDING', self.do_something)`. I see no requirement of using lambda here. Secondly your   *"Now here the event is passed as the first argument which here is self not event"* doesn't make much sense. when you use `self.somemethod` the instance of the class is passed as the first argument, the second argument event will be passed to the event parameter in this case.

Comment: @Art, Yes you are right, Thanks for reviewing and letting me know the problems with my answers, I will make sure to edit and make the answer as suitable as possible.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that the lambda way of doing it, is still valid and it can be used as an alternative too. But your explanation of the actual problem of the OP, does indicate that lambda way is not the best way of doing it.

Comment: @Art I have made the necessary changes in my answer, I hope it is more suitable to the question now. Again thanks for letting me know of the mistakes in there.